# Series where the protagonists fly a plane out of an underground base, episode with a water talisman

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I have forgotten this show for a long time but it's on the edge of my memory. Please help me get my nostalgia boost. No wiki or IMDb can help me so far.

I saw a cartoon show a long time ago about monsters. The protagonist team had a cool sci-fi airplane that came from underground, with doors splitting to bring it up. One of the (early?) episodes is about some sort of water talisman that a female mermaid or other creature had.

The series might have something to do with monster cards, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This could use some additional details; you should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you remember anything.  Any idea how long ago this was?

Comment: Was one of the agents a banshee?

Comment: It was a western cartoon, i believe. A waterfall or something with water moved when the doors for the sci-fi ship opened. It was a kids series from about 15-20 years ago. It was very likely aired on dutch television. Therwas also a female teacher that was brought into the world and who did not know the world at all, like it was an accident she got there. I do not remember a banshee, but it could be.

Comment: Ah, by "brought into the world", do you mean this was a separate world? Or just that she was inducted into the mystery.

Comment: And by "monster cards", were they informational? A way to catch the monsters? Monstrous cards?

Comment: Sorry I dont remember those details exactly. I think they had a way of identifying the monsters with the cards, but I cannot say with certainty. I think the ship brought them to another dimension or world, seperate from earth.

Comment: @RoelandDraayer Your comment on water moving for the airplane to launch puts me in mind of the Hawkwing launch from Terrahawks where the plane flies up through a vortex of water in a lake https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwvciYGn1F4